# Running JMeter via a shortcut?

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, shortcut

I am trying to create a shortcut outside the bin folder to run Jmeter, but no matter what I do, after Jmeter runs, and I try and execute my test, I get this error -

`Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os /Kernel32. See log file for details.`

I have tried -

- A shortcut using "c:\windows\explorer.exe path\to\jmeter.bat"
- A batch file cd'ing into the bin dir and running the jmeter.bat
- A batch file cd'ing into the bin dir then runnin "java -jar ApacheJmeter.jar"

All three execute Jmeter fine, but my test won't run as per the error above..if I run the bat or jar directly in the bin folder, my tests working..

Someone must have run Jmeter from a shortcut before?

Comment: Not sure why you would trying to run a batch file with explorer.exe. That makes no sense at all.  You would normally use cmd.exe. When you do a change directory, that can be dependent on what drive you are currently in and what drive you want to go to.  Which is why it has the /D option.

Comment: If you look online on how to make a relative shortcut, this seems to be the suggested option on how to do it...

Answer (score 2):

One alternative way you can use if I'm thinking right -

1. Move to your `jmeter` bin folder
2. Right click on `jmeter.bat` file
3. Select `send to > Desktop(create shortcut)`

Answer (score 0):

I usually add the jmeter path to the system path in windows. Edit the windows path and add the full path of your jmeter bin folder. After that, you can invoke jmeter.bat from anywhere.

```
echo %PATH%
......;C:\Software\jmeter3\bin
```

Now, I can invoke jmeter from anywhere like

```
c:\jmeter.bat
```